# Use "alter system" from C# for ORACLE 10g database

Tags: c#-4.0, oracle10g, odp.net

I need for some reason to alter and show the size of db_cahce_size for an ORACLE 10g database from C# (using ODP.NET) I use the following commands on SQL+

"`alter system set db_cache_size = Xm scope=both;`"

and that command to show it current value

"`show parameter db_cache_size;`"

but when I tried to issue that commands from C# via ODP.NET command object I got that error
[***ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement***]

It seems that it doesn't accept such kind of command so What to do please to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just create a small procedure to alter the system:

```sql
create or replace procedure change_cache_size (Px in number) is
begin
   execute immediate 'alter system set db_cache_size = Xm scope=both';
end;
```

You can then call this from C#.

In order to find the current value of a parameter in SQL you can query [V$PARAMETER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/dynviews_2085.htm#REFRN30176)

```sql
select value
  from v$parameter
 where name = 'db_cache_size'
```

This can then be queried normally. Alternatively, you can combine them into one using an OUT parameter.

```sql
create or replace procedure change_cache_size (Psize out varchar2) is
begin
   execute immediate 'alter system set db_cache_size = Xm scope=both';

   select value into Psize
     from v$parameter
    where name = 'db_cache_size';
end;
```

I would be *extremely* wary of changing an initialization parameter in an application in this manner. It's highly indicative that something needs to be changed in your database. I would be much more comfortable coming up with a cache size that works for all applications using a database rather than changing it based on the requirements of one at a single moment in time.

If you want X to be variable then simply make this another parameter:

```sql
create or replace procedure change_cache_size (PX in number, Psize out varchar2) is
begin
   execute immediate 'alter system set db_cache_size = ' || X || 'm scope=both';

   select value into Psize
     from v$parameter
    where name = 'db_cache_size';
end;
```

It's worth noting that you'd now be performing system changes dynamically with user input... ensure you sanitise the input first.

Comment: Nice, but can you tell me how to set X as parameter plus how to create this from SQL+

Comment: I've updated my answer @DigitalFox. To create simply run and then on the next like add a `/`. If you want to see errors just type `show errors` after that...

Comment: I'm so grateful to you Mr. Ben. amazing :)